# Bundle package with custom declaration file and import in other project

Tags: typescript, export, vite, bundle, type-declaration

So I have been trying developing own package: [dicom-web-anonymizer (dwa)](https://github.com/openradx/dicom-anonymizer) which relies on a third-party package called [dcmjs](https://github.com/dcmjs-org/dcmjs). As dcmjs is not typed, I created my own declaration file under /types. That worked, and now I wanted to test and bundle everything with vite and import my package inside another project [ADIT (upload branch)](https://github.com/openradx/adit/tree/upload_new). As I am using `dcmjs` also in `ADIT`, I imported it there in the `core_layout.hmtl`, declared it in globals.d.ts and everything works fine.  I declared dcmjs as external in my vite.config.ts in `dwa` and made sure I imported it after `dcmjs`in my `core_layout.html`.

Here my current `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: "./src/index.ts",
      formats: ["umd"],
      name: "dicom-web-anonymizer",
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: "dicom-web-anonymizer",
    },

    sourcemap: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: "./src/index.ts",
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ["dcmjs", "fs", "get-random-values"],
      output: {
        format: "umd",
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          dcmjs: "dcmjs",
          fs: "fs",
          "get-random-values": "get-Random-Values",
        },
        plugins: [dts()],
      },
    },
  },
});
```

and `index.ts` in my demo-vite project is only:

`export { Anonymizer } from "../../src/anonymizer.ts";`
Note: the `Anonymizer`class is everything I want to export and my sole entrypoint to the whole module.

Now my question: I have no idea what I am doing wrong and how I need to import my .umd.cjs files and how I can basically just get a line like

`const anon = new Anonymizer();`

to work.

I tried to include just the .js files but it also doesnt work.
I am new to module formats like `es` or `umd` so I am not exactly familiar what their differences are and how exports from bundled packages work like in the different ways.